# Converter Data SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de converter`02/01/2018` para `2018-01-02 00:00:00.000`, o que eu encontrei na internet até agora foi:

```
select CONVERT (datetime, '02/01/2018', 120)
```

Que me retorna`2018-02-01 00:00:00.000`, um pouco diferente do que preciso.

Qual numero devo usar no lugar do `120`?

Comment: Conheça os estilos de data e hora em https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36773962/4551469) do SO, o código que você deseja é o `103`:

```
select CONVERT (datetime, '02/01/2018', 103)
```

Answer (score -2):

108 trás as horas também.

`SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME, '02/01/2018', 103) + ' ' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR, nomedacoluna, 108)`